# How to put two different size tables side by side

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

Similar questions are asked but they are all for same size table what I am looking for when there are two tables when one of them is short how to put a short one with the same bottom level as the tall one?

I created a figure in the paint to show what I am trying to do.
Edit: Sample code

[image: figure]

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
    \caption{Global caption}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
      \centering
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
  \hline
 \# knots & AIC & BIC \\ 
  \hline
  1 & 322625.83 & 322868.78 \\ 
  2 & 321432.75 & 321666.71 \\ 
  3 & 321761.76 & 322004.71 \\ 
  4 & 320820.95 & 321072.90 \\ 
  5 & 320912.06 & 321173.01 \\ 
  6 & 320423.63 & 320693.58 \\ 
  7 & 320526.15 & 320805.09 \\ 
  8 & 320310.71 & 320598.65 \\ 
  9 & 320383.00 & 320679.94 \\ 
  10 & 320247.17 & 320553.11 \\ 
  11 & 320281.47 & 320596.41 \\ 
  12 & 320235.23 & 320559.17 \\ 
  13 & 320207.29 & 320540.22 \\ 
  14 & 320235.88 & 320577.82 \\ 
  15 & 320120.00 & 320470.93 \\ 
  16 & 320208.19 & 320568.12 \\ 
  17 & 319964.00 & 320332.93 \\ 
  18 & 320037.99 & 320415.92 \\ 
  19 & 320090.17 & 320477.09 \\ 
  20 & 319771.52 & 320167.44 \\ 
  21 & 319793.34 & 320198.26 \\ 
  \textbf{22} & \textbf{319718.50} & \textbf{320132.42} \\ 
  23 & 319819.55 & 320242.46 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{AICbsX} (a)}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
      \centering
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
  \hline
 \# knots & AIC & BIC \\ 
  \hline
1 & 320699.70 & 321095.62 \\ 
  2 & 320466.72 & 320853.65 \\ 
  3 & 319899.46 & 320295.38 \\ 
  4 & 320113.59 & 320518.51 \\ 
  5 & 319718.50 & 320132.42 \\ 
  6 & 319802.50 & 320225.42 \\ 
  7 & 319732.82 & 320164.74 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{AICbsY} (b)}
    \end{minipage} 
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us, what you try o far! Those table you can put in `minipage` with position option `[b]` ...

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are putting captions below the two tabulars, you might as well use subtable from the subcaption package.  The [b] for subtable aligns the last baseline, which is actually the first baseline of the caption.  The [b] for tabular is in case you decide to lose the captions.

If you aren't using twocolumn, just replace table* with table.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[t]
    \caption{Global caption}
\begin{subtable}[b]{.5\linewidth}
      \centering
\begin{tabular}[b]{rrr}
  \hline
 \# knots & AIC & BIC \\ 
  \hline
  1 & 322625.83 & 322868.78 \\ 
  2 & 321432.75 & 321666.71 \\ 
  3 & 321761.76 & 322004.71 \\ 
  4 & 320820.95 & 321072.90 \\ 
  5 & 320912.06 & 321173.01 \\ 
  6 & 320423.63 & 320693.58 \\ 
  7 & 320526.15 & 320805.09 \\ 
  8 & 320310.71 & 320598.65 \\ 
  9 & 320383.00 & 320679.94 \\ 
  10 & 320247.17 & 320553.11 \\ 
  11 & 320281.47 & 320596.41 \\ 
  12 & 320235.23 & 320559.17 \\ 
  13 & 320207.29 & 320540.22 \\ 
  14 & 320235.88 & 320577.82 \\ 
  15 & 320120.00 & 320470.93 \\ 
  16 & 320208.19 & 320568.12 \\ 
  17 & 319964.00 & 320332.93 \\ 
  18 & 320037.99 & 320415.92 \\ 
  19 & 320090.17 & 320477.09 \\ 
  20 & 319771.52 & 320167.44 \\ 
  21 & 319793.34 & 320198.26 \\ 
  \textbf{22} & \textbf{319718.50} & \textbf{320132.42} \\ 
  23 & 319819.55 & 320242.46 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{}\label{AICbsX}
\end{subtable}%
\begin{subtable}[b]{.5\linewidth}
      \centering
\begin{tabular}[b]{rrr}
  \hline
 \# knots & AIC & BIC \\ 
  \hline
1 & 320699.70 & 321095.62 \\ 
  2 & 320466.72 & 320853.65 \\ 
  3 & 319899.46 & 320295.38 \\ 
  4 & 320113.59 & 320518.51 \\ 
  5 & 319718.50 & 320132.42 \\ 
  6 & 319802.50 & 320225.42 \\ 
  7 & 319732.82 & 320164.74 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{}\label{AICbsY}
\end{subtable} 
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. :-) I would add `\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{b} \let\B\textbf` after `\begin{table}` in order to use the non-extended bold font weight for numbers in the table.

Comment: This is an awesome small fix, thanks!!